# How to declare an int array with a constant?

Tags: java, arrays, constants

I'm a really basic beginner at Java and I've been trying to figure out how to declare arrays.
If I want to use a constant int SIZE that is set equal to 5, would it be any different from declaring a regular array?

From what I've learned, this is one way to declare an array:

```
int intArray[] = new int[3];
```

And this would give an array from 1 to 3, I think...

Comment: [Java arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `int SIZE = 3; int[] intArray = new int[SIZE];`

Comment: correction, you will get an array from 0 to 2

Comment: Would I have to initialize each element up to the constant?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you declare constants by using the `final` keyword:

```
final int SIZE = 5;
```

then, you can use this constant to initialize your array:

```
int intArray[] = new int[SIZE];
```

**Note:**

- Indices in most programming languages start with `0`. So, to access the elements of the array, you will have to use indices starting from `0`:

  ```
  intArray[0]    -> first element
  intArray[1]    -> second element
  intArray[2]    -> third element
  ```

**Edit:**

- If you tried to access to the array using `intArray[SIZE]`, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you can only access with indices between `0` and `SIZE - 1`. Note that in this range there are `SIZE` numbers of elements.

Comment: If I wrote: System.out.println(intArray[SIZE]);
That would only print out 5, correct?

Comment: @Kirikiriyu  No, you can only access with indices between `0` and `SIZE - 1`.